# Cannot find the library in Eclipse for a C++ code to connect to MySQL

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll, static-libraries, mysql-connector

I am trying to run this code that I got from the internet, but I will get an error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibmysql.lib'
```

and

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

while building it. I am using Eclipse with MinGW to connect to MySQL. 
I have added the:

```
C:\Program Files\boost
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include
```

to the include directory and

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.2\lib\opt
```

to Library Directories (-L). Also I added the

```
libmysql.lib
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

to Additional Dependencies (-l).

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#define host "localhost"
#define username "root"
#define password "root"
#define database "tests"

int main()
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init( NULL );
    if( conn )
    {
        mysql_real_connect( conn, host, username, password, database, 0, NULL, 0 );
    }
    MYSQL_RES* res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    unsigned int i;
    mysql_query( conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_clients WHERE id = 1" );
    res_set = mysql_store_result( conn );
    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows( res_set );
    if( numrows )
    {
        row = mysql_fetch_row( res_set );
        if( row != NULL )
        {
            cout << "Client ID  : " << row[0] << endl;
            cout << "Client Name: " << row[1] << endl;
        }
    }
    if( res_set )
    {
        mysql_free_result( res_set );
    }
    if( conn )
    {
        mysql_close( conn );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I'm new to this stuff

Comment: Can you show linker command path?

Comment: @Lol4t0
The Linker paths are:
[C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib] [C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.2\lib\opt]

Comment: I mean, command that invokes linker, like `g++ file.cpp -Lblala -lfoo -lbar....`

Comment: @Lol4t0 It is ' g++ "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib" "-LD:\\Boost\\boost_1_53_0" "-LC:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\Connector C++ 1.1.3\\lib\\opt" -o TestSql-2.exe Test.o -llibmysql.lib -lmysqlcppconn-static.lib'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the .lib from the end of the     libmysql.lib